# Writing Pandas Dataframes as well as numpy arrays to a common Excel File

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, xlsxwriter

Using Python 3.6 and Pandas 0.22 I have created a pandas dataframe `IRdaily` with time series of daily changes in various interest rates. I can easily write the Pandas dataframe to Excel using the commands:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outFileName)
IRdaily.to_excel(writer, 'Daily Changes')
```

But if I now compute the eigenvalue decomposition (both the vector of eigenvalues and the matrix of eigenvectors are numpy ndarrays) and try to write them to the same worksheet I get an error:

```
covD  = deltaIRdaily.cov()
eigValD, eigVecD = np.linalg.eigh(covD)
eigValD.to_excel(writer, 'Daily Changes', startcol = 15) 
eigVecD.to_excel(writer, 'Daily Changes', startrow = 15, startcol = 15) 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Documents\Python\FedInterestRateDataExtract.py", line 58, in <module>
    eigValD.to_excel(writer, 'Daily Changes', startcol = 15)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

How can I write ndarrays to a specified row and column in an existing worksheet in an open workbook? It's being done correctly with Pandas dataframes, so I'm guessing that there must be a simple way in which to write the results of any analysis of the data held in a Pandas dataframe.

Many thanks in advance for your advice and assistance

Thomas Philips

Answer (score 4):

First, note that [`to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) is a method on `DataFrame`, so it should not be too surprising that it fails when invoked on an `np.ndarray`.

Regarding the actual problem, it's quite a roundabout way of doing it, but since you already have a `pd.ExcelWriter` set up, I would suggest simply turning the two arrays into `DataFrame`s, doing instead something that amounts to

```
pd.DataFrame(eigValD).to_excel(writer, 'Daily Changes', startcol=15, header=False, index=False)
```

A more direct way would be to just use `xlsxwriter` directly.

Comment: Thanks for this. You mention that it's a roundabout way of doing this. I'd be very appreciative if you would point me to the t

Comment: I'd be very appreciative if you would point out to me to the right way to do this

Comment: @ThomasPhilips, As far as I'm aware you can't export NumPy arrays to excel directly. I recommend you use this answer.

Comment: @ThomasPhilips: The alternative I had in mind would be to just pass the NumPy array to `xlsxwriter` directly, cf. e.g. https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html, rather than going through pandas. In some cases this could be preferable as you avoid the dependency on pandas and its API, but since you're already using pandas here, you of course might as well keep it simple.